# MySQL select 9 random and 1 defined record

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My question is pretty straightforward, how do I select 9 random records and one defined record in the same SQL statement? All I can think of so far is this, which only returns the one partner record (the defined one) but not the other 9 random ones.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE filename = '$partn' AND filename != '$x' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10";
```

To elaborate, I need ten records to be returned, none of then should be '$x', one of them should be '$partn' and then 9 other random ones, they all need to be displayed in a random order.

Any help would be appreciated!:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE file='$x')
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE file<>'$x' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9)
```

Comment: It would be good if the first `SELECT` has `LIMIT 1`. just in case.

Answer (score 4):

use union:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

```
(select the one you want)
union
(select 9 randoms that arent the one you want)
```